# Libgdx box2d ContactListener is extremely glitchy

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, collision

I run into this situation while developing my little 2D side-scrolling platformer game using libgdx. The main problem is that `beginContact(Contact contact)` isn't called when it clearly needs to. Here are some simplified code snippets to give a quick overview:

`ContactListener` class which logs every contact between sensor and ground:

```
public class WorldContactListener implements ContactListener
{
Player player;

public WorldContactListener(Player player, World world)
{
    this.player = player;
    world.setContactListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact)
{
    Object userDataA = contact.getFixtureA().getUserData();
    Object userDataB = contact.getFixtureB().getUserData();

    if((userDataA == Tomb.UserData.GROUND || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.GROUND) 
  && (userDataA == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET  || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET))
    {   
        Gdx.app.log("collision", "start");
    } 
}

@Override
public void endContact(Contact contact) 
{
    Object userDataA = contact.getFixtureA().getUserData();
    Object userDataB = contact.getFixtureB().getUserData();

    if((userDataA == Tomb.UserData.GROUND || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.GROUND) 
  && (userDataA == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET  || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET))
    {   
        Gdx.app.log("collision", "stop");
    } 
}

@Override
public void preSolve(Contact contact, Manifold oldManifold) 
{
}

@Override
public void postSolve(Contact contact, ContactImpulse impulse) 
{
}
}
```

Player creation:

```
    //Main rectangle:
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(spawnCoordinates);
    bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    shape.setAsBox(5 / Tomb.PPM, 14 / Tomb.PPM);
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    fixtureDef.friction = FRICTION; //1
    fixtureDef.restitution = RESTITUTION; //0
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(Tomb.UserData.PLAYER);

    //Circle-shaped sensor:
    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape feet = new CircleShape();
    feet.setPosition(new Vector2(0, -16 / Tomb.PPM));
    feet.setRadius(10 / Tomb.PPM);
    fixtureDef.shape = feet;
    fixtureDef.isSensor = true; 
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET);
```

Player movements:

```
private void handleInput(float delta)
{
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP))
    {
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, JUMP_POWER), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && body.getLinearVelocity().x <= MAX_HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY)
    {
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(HORIZONTAL_SPEED, 0), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && body.getLinearVelocity().x >= -MAX_HORIZONTAL_VELOCITY)
    {
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-HORIZONTAL_SPEED, 0), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
}
```

Initialization of a .tmx map, which is imported from Tiled Map Editor. It's noteworthy that whole terrain is one single `PolygonMapObject`, so specifically in this case `for` loop isn't needed.

```
protected void defineGround(int layerIndex) 
{
    for(PolygonMapObject object : map.getLayers().get(layerIndex).getObjects().getByType(PolygonMapObject.class))
    {
        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        ChainShape chainShape = new ChainShape();
        FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
        Body body;

        Polygon polygon = object.getPolygon();
        bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;
        bodyDef.position.set(polygon.getX() / Tomb.PPM, polygon.getY() / Tomb.PPM);
        body = world.createBody(bodyDef);   
        float[] scaledVertices = new float[polygon.getVertices().length];
        for(int i = 0; i < polygon.getVertices().length; i++)
        {
            scaledVertices[i] = polygon.getVertices()[i] / Tomb.PPM;
        }
        chainShape.createChain(scaledVertices);
        fixtureDef.shape = chainShape;
        body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(Tomb.UserData.GROUND);
    }
}
```

Finally, self-explaining pics, which show the game screen itself and eclipse console with `WorldContactListener` logs:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Same thing happens when trying to climb up the slope (or absolutely any non-flat surface):

[image]
[image]

I have tried all possible sensor shape and size variations, so this behavior isn't caused by `CircleShape`'s size. What could be the case? Or any workaround which doesn't involve `ContactListener`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deal is that there ale multiple collisions at one time. On your last image u can see that there are still (2-1 + 2-1) = 2 collisions between your player and polygons.

Here is my example solution:
Make some collision counter class with functions incCollision() and decCollision(), and maybe some bool isCollison() that will tell you if there actually is any collision.

Edit your ContactListener class:

```
public void beginContact(Contact contact)
{
...
   if((userDataA == Tomb.UserData.GROUND || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.GROUND) 
      && (userDataA == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET  || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET))
        {   
            Gdx.app.log("collision", "start");
            counter.incCollision();
        } 
}

public void endContact(Contact contact)
{
...
if((userDataA == Tomb.UserData.GROUND || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.GROUND) 
  && (userDataA == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET  || userDataB == Tomb.UserData.PLAYER_FEET))
    {   
        Gdx.app.log("collision", "stop");
        counter.decCollision();
    } 
}
```